# Is it possible to build radar system for drones detection at home?

Tags: microcontroller, detection, radar, drone

Can I build DIY radar system using ESP32 or Raspberry Pi modules + a bit of soldering that will be able to detect drones in a radius 1-2km? Is it possible? What do I need for this and how much will it cost?

I need a system which will be able to detect a position of drone if it flies inside of radar radius (like a radar in airports).

Comment: Even the tools to develop this are prohibitively expensive. The level of money you can buy houses for. But you can probably DIY a radar that can see walls.

Comment: Build a scale model S-300 battery.  That way you can shoot em down too!  Or a scale model AEGIS destroyer, but that would be much more expensive due to the phased array.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It will be expensive, since you'll need to hire an experienced RF engineer to design it, make the prototype, then pass the prototype through certification needed to legally operate it. And you'll likely need a license for a fixed radar installation.

Very simple things like those microwave radar speed indicating road signs require operating licenses in most places, never mind the burden of compliance certification.

What you're looking for is an actual radar that has sensitivity similar to terminal defense radars that protect tanks or small ships against incoming missiles/artillery shells/grenades. It'd deal with slower targets and slower scan speeds, so the signal processing will be much easier. But the radio cross-sections of consumer drones at a distance of 1-2km are similar to the cross-sections of small artillery shells at similar distances.

Just the RF hardware needed to pull this off in any reasonable amount of time will cost a pretty penny. Given the size of the drones, you'd be looking at an S, C or X band radar (15cm to 2.5cm wavelength range). For loitering or slowly maneuvering drone detection, you could use old-school approach: azimuth scan and elevation scan, with a single RF channel. You'll need relatively large antennas, mechanical scanning, etc. A phased array antenna would be way outside of any reasonable budget.

You'd end up with something that would rather resemble a scaled-down military air defense or flight approach guidance radar from decades ago - those that had a vertically- and a horizontally-oriented antenna, oval- or rectangular-shaped. Interestingly enough, that stuff doesn't get any cheaper with time. And even if you *could* make this, it'd be likely export-limited and not a project you could openly document without facing rather stiff penalties. You're basically talking of low-end military capability here.

So, is it possible? Sure: the "at home" part is relative. Wealthy people live in homes too, you know. So, if you got the money and the know how, or can afford someone with the know-how, and are ready to navigate the governmental bureaucracy and fees needed to get this thing legally operating - go for it. But no, it won't be anything like soldering some bits and pieces you can buy at the Arduino or RPi Foundation store together.

Comment: It's for our soldiers. I think they can close eyes on licenses if it saves lives

Comment: @Robotex Very true. In active war, anything goes. There are cheap-er ways of doing this in such an environment. Detecting the azimuth of a drone with rotating blades or a propeller can be done with a UHF CW transmitter and a receiver with a directional antenna. You can literally hear the blades that way. Triangulation can be used to figure out the location. If the drone transmits anything, this can also be used with triangulation and direction finding. So there are easy ways but they are more for fixed area protection. Portable radar for this is hard.

Comment: In good weather, optical methods would also work. You could scan the space with an IR laser beam and look for reflections. Once a reflection is found, an off-the-shelf time-of-flight chip can determine the distance. Power hungry and heavy due to optics, and not super fast, but probably could be made to work as well.

Comment: Sounds interesting. Yes, it's for fixed area. I though about protection from enemy artillery forces drones.

> "UHF CW transmitter and a receiver with a directional antenna"

Could you recommend me some modules if it available in civil market?

> "IR laser beam and look for reflections"

What can I use for reflections detections? IR camera? But this way is demasking the system in night vision systems. But I can add turning on/off this feature just for increasing the accuracy of detection if safe to use.

Answer (score 2):

You might have better luck with an optical system - the quick-and-dirty solution is to station somebody with a pair of binoculars, although you might consider teaching an AI system to spot drones.  It’s not directly an answer to the ‘is it possible’ question but may achieve the objective.